# Extracting content of variable in XML-files

Tags: regex, xml, notepad++, extract

I have over one hundred XML files with thousands of lines of the following:

`<filler name="1" subject="Test subject">
'
<content subject="Test subject" date="2017-20-11" author="testuauthor1">Blah</content>
<content subject="Test subject" date="2017-20-11" author="testuauthor2">Blah</content>
<content subject="Test subject" date="2017-20-11" author="testuauthor3">Blah</content>
'
</filler>`

I'm trying to find a way to extract the content of 'author', so all that is left is this:

`testauthor1
 testauthor2
 testauthor3`

I have attempted to use regex in Notepad++. What I have right now is the following code:

`(author[\=\"].*[\"\>])`

I'm pretty new to Regex, but I found the above in another excellent thread on here. I'm using it with Notepad++'s search function. It does highlight `by="author"`, but also the rest of the line, ie. `></content>`, meaning the content of 'content' is also highlighted, which is a problem.

So this obviously isn't a solution. And **even** if I managed to highlight each individual `by="author"`, I would need to copy paste every single one of them into a new document, but we're talking hundreds of thousands of occurances.

I have searched for hours for a solution, but maybe I'm missing something obvious. I even tried converting each .xml file into a .csv and stripping everything in the .csv document but the 'author' column. It's not a viable solution, though.

I would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction as to what to do here. I have never tried anything like this.  Thanks!

Comment: Try `\bauthor="([^"]+)"|(?s:.)` and replace with `(?1$1\n:)` in NPP search and replace window.

Comment: James, did anything work for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Regex is the wrong tool for parsing XML.  Use XPath instead.**

For example:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/filler/content/@author" test.xml
```

will return

```
testuauthor1
testuauthor2
testuauthor3
```

as requested.